# Consumer/Producer with ExecutorService is stuck

Tags: java, multithreading, producer-consumer, blockingqueue

I'm new to multi threading and I'm trying to write the following simple program:

1. Read a file
2. Print the output to screen

I've created the following Classes: Consumer

```
public class Consumer implements Runnable {
    private BlockingQueue<String> m_Queue;

public Consumer(BlockingQueue<String> i_Queue)
{
    m_Queue = i_Queue;
}

@Override
public void run()
{
    try
    {
        String referenceID1;

        //Consuming message until exit message is received.
        while((referenceID1 = m_Queue.take()) !="EOF")
        {
            System.out.println(referenceID1);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```

Producer:

```
public class Producer implements Runnable {
private BlockingQueue<String> m_Queue;
private String m_FilePath;

public Producer(BlockingQueue<String> i_Queue, String i_FilePath)
{
    m_Queue = i_Queue;
    m_FilePath = i_FilePath;
}

@Override
public void run()
{
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(m_FilePath)))
    {
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            m_Queue.put(line);
            System.out.println(line + " Was added to queue.");
        }

        //Adding an exit message.
        m_Queue.put("EOF");
        System.out.println("EOF Was added to queue.");
    }
    catch (IOException | InterruptedException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```

ProducerConsumerService

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    BlockingQueue<String> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(100);

    //Start the producer; Will read the file
    threadPool.execute(new Producer(queue, args[0]));

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Generating consumer " + i+1);
        threadPool.execute(new Consumer(queue));
    }

    try
    {
        threadPool.shutdown();
        System.out.println("Shutting down threads.");

        threadPool.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
        System.out.println("Terminated successfully.");
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } }
```

The input file consists of the numbers 1-20, each number in a new line.
When I run the program, I can see that all numbers are read, but the program seems to hang/stuck and I don't see the "Terminated successfully" message.
This doesn't happen if I use a single thread for reading and a single thread for printing on screen, but using 1 thread defies my need of a "multi-threaded" program. 
My guess is that I'm forgetting to release a resource, but I have no idea why.

Comment: Please replace `(referenceID1 = m_Queue.take()) !="EOF"` with `!(referenceID1 = m_Queue.take()).equals("EOF")`. String comparison with `==` is very unlikely to work.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon You're correct. But as Nicolas Filotto suggested, I completely removed the EOF part. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you use `take()` in your `Consumer` which:

> Retrieves and removes the head of this queue, waiting if necessary
>   until an element becomes available.

And you test if the returned value is `EOF` (not properly BTW you need to use equals) but you put it only once into your queue and you have 4 `Consumer` so 3 `Consumer` still wait for it.

So you should use `poll()` instead as below:

```
while((referenceID1 = m_Queue.poll()) != null && !Objects.equals(referenceID1, "EOF"))
```

Or simply if you get rid of `EOF`

```
while((referenceID1 = m_Queue.poll()) != null)
```

Comment: @ocp1000 good news, yes indeed "EOF" isn't needed anymore with this approach